# What is wrong with my association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, model-associations

I am looking to setup a relationship where a user can create a post and tag that post. That post and those tags belong to that user.

I've been trying to debug this for the last three days. I don't know why when I save my Post, the user_id does not populate in the Tag model. I added the user_id into the Tag model.

I apologize in advance for the excessive code.

User - has_many posts; has_many tags

Post - belongs_to user; has_many taggings; has_many tags through taggings

Tag - has many taggings; has_many posts through taggings; belongs_to user

Tagging - belongs_to post; belongs_to tag

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20121031012555) do

  create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "summary"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
  end

  create_table "taggings", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.integer  "tag_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  add_index "taggings", ["post_id"], :name => "index_taggings_on_post_id"
  add_index "taggings", ["tag_id"], :name => "index_taggings_on_tag_id"

  create_table "tags", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "crypted_password"
    t.string   "password_salt"
    t.string   "persistence_token"
    t.datetime "created_at",        :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        :null => false
    t.string   "role"
  end

end
```

In the post Model:

```
def tag_ids=(tags_string)
    self.taggings.destroy_all

    tag_names = tags_string.split(",").collect{|s| s.strip.downcase}.uniq
    tag_names.each do |tag_name|
      tag = Tag.find_or_create_by_name(tag_name)
      tagging = self.taggings.new
      tagging.tag_id = tag.id
    end
end
```

Comment: You could use `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation for that. That helps you to avoid that dummy destroy.

Comment: You are not save `taggings` after assigning `tagging.tag_id = tag.id`. And I don't see where you trying to save `user_id`

Comment: @ck3g This is the gist he made for this: https://gist.github.com/4025471

Comment: @ck3g HABTM is just a simpler many to many association. It should be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize if I'm missing something, but it looks like you're not passing user id to the tag when it gets created. With rails 3 you can do your find_or_create_by for more than one attribute, like so:

```
tag = Tag.find_or_create_by_name_and_user_id(tag_name, user_id)
```

In addition, if you only want to build the Tag object, but not immediately save it to the DB, you may use the "find_or_initialize_by..." method, like so:

```
tag = Tag.find_or_initialize_by_name_and_user(tag_name, user)
```

Just make sure your Tag model has `attr_accessible :user_id` if it doesn't already.

**Update:** Sorry I just re-read your question, and you stated that you do pass the user_id in to the tag model. However I don't see that in the code you provided; where does that occur?

**Update #2**
Based on the comment thread, your parameter map does not contain the user_id; this is, of course, because the parameter map is built from the form inputs, which apparently does not contain an input for the user.

I'm going under the assumption that when a post is created, it should be associated with the currently logged in user. I will also assume that you have, somewhere, available a reference to the currently logged in user, which I'm going to call @current_user.

Since it looks like you want to create the post and associated tags in one atomic operation,  one thing you can do add the current user to a copy of the parameter map, like so:

```
post_params = params.clone.store(:user=>@current_user)
@post = Post.new(post_params)
```

There may be a better way of doing this, but this should work. Note that you probably don't need to make a clone of the parameter map; I admin I'm not sure what is best practice in this case.

Regardless, hope that helps.

**update 3**
Since a Ruby hash is iterated over in the order in which the keys are inserted, svn's tag_ids were being set BEFORE his user_id in to the Post model. In order to solve the problem, svn reversed the order of my previous suggestion, and ensured that the :user key was inserted before any other value. This is one possible solution (modified from svn's gist(https://gist.github.com/4027807)):

```
post_params = {:user => current_user}.merge!(params[:post].clone)
@post = Post.new(post_params)
```

Comment: So my tag_ids is a virtual attribute stored in a model. I've tried the  find_or_create_by_name_and_user_id but I can't get the user_id information in Post model (where tag_ids is stored). My tag model does have attr_accessible :user_id. I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong or how to do this.

Comment: @svn Ah ok, I didn't get that tag_ids was in the Post model. So, if the Post model has a user association, how come you can't get the user using something like `tag.user = self.user` (`self` being the current Post instance of course)? Does that make sense? Sorry again if I'm still missing something.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought too! When I was debugging, the self.user is nil. In the Post controller, when the original @post = Post.new(params[:post]) is instantiated, it runs through the tag_ids= method, at that point the self.user is nil .. I've been reading but I can't find whether if this should be the case and if not where I could be going wrong. I've put the code in a gist https://gist.github.com/4025471

Comment: You need to specify the user some where like, @post = Post.new(:user_id => current_user.id) or you can specify that in your view as well(you can pass user_id value from views as a hidden field)

Comment: am confused about what you are trying to achieve. can you elaborate "when I save my Post, the user_id does not populate in the Tag model"

Comment: Sure, so I have a tag model that has attributes of :name and :user_id. A tag belongs_to user and has_many posts, through tagging. When that post is created the tag model stores the name but does not associate that tag with a user through the user_id attribute. Say for example I use your previous code of Tag.find_or_create_by_name_and_user_id(name, 1) this works perfectly except I don't know how to make it so the current_user replaces the 1.

Comment: @svn When you pass the params to the Post model (`Post.new(params[:post]`), are you certain that the user_id is in the parameter map? Do a `logger.debug params[:post].to_s` to find out.

Comment: It does not seem so. If I put logger.debug params[:post].to_s after the @post = Post.new(params[:post]) the summary, tag, and created at show up but not the user_id... not sure why this would be?

Comment: @svn Ah ha, so there's your problem. I'm updating my answer with some new info...

Comment: It was looking promising, instead of store I used merge! ..the post_params showed the user_id, however, when debugging in the model, the user information doesn't go to the model, I get user_id: nil only the summary information ( not the created_at etc which makes sense because at that point the post hasn't been created) It seems like the new params isn't being passed to the model method? what.. am .. I missing! haha I also tried several variations of the cloning hash

Comment: @svn Oh ok. Try to switch the order of the parameter map; make sure that :user is first, BEFORE your tag_ids. I'm trying to think of a better way, but that should work in the short term.

Comment: @Teeg, that works! Amazing. It does look sloppy.. I created a new gist to show the new version. https://gist.github.com/4027807 .. also I'm quite sure why having the order of the params matters?

Comment: Teeg, thanks for all your help, appreciate it! I'll send over some reputation points

Comment: @svn No problem, glad we could help.

Comment: @Teeg, care to explain why you thought of switching the params order?

Comment: @svn Your parameter map contains the `tag_ids` key-value pair. Your rails model, when it is passed a hash (such as the params map) iterates through each of the key-value pairs, and calls the setter-method with the same name as the key (for example `tag_ids`, or `user_id`, etc). The hash is iterated over in the order the keys were originally inserted (See http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html). Since you were originally adding the user_id AFTER the params was already put together, your `tag_ids=(value)` method would have been called first BEFORE the `user_id=(value)` method, hence the null.

Answer (score 0):

before the line in your controller,

```
@post = Post.new(params[:post])
```

Add below line

```
@post = Post.new(:user_id => <assign your required user_id>)
```

This will make new post object to use user_id inside its instace method.
Then you will be able to use,below line successfully

```
tag = Tag.find_or_create_by_name_and_user_id(tag_name, user_id)
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you're saying here. Before which line?

Comment: in your create method, before the line "@post = Post.new(params[:post])", you should add the given line, to specify your post belongs to a particular user